# Are two instance instantiate differently behave the same?

Tags: java

```
Object a=new Object();
Orange o=(Orange)a;


Orange orange=new Orange();
```

Both o and orange are instatiate in different way. Are they behave the same? (can call all the instance method and field of Orange class)

Comment: nooooooooooooo, `a` is not an Orange! You cannot cast it to Orange.

Comment: One of my suggestion by which you will never get confused for any java fundamental in future. Read SCJP Kathy Sierra your all fundamentals will be getting cleared. Once read it Here is the link for download http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Focjp.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FSCJP%2520Sun%2520Certified%2520Programmer%2520for%2520Java%25206%2520Exam%2520310-065.pdf&ei=_reUUa_fFcfmrAfGtYAQ&usg=AFQjCNHU9tYlrGZ67TwDqvFmLC7v7ksJag&bvm=bv.46471029,d.bmk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. `a` is not an Orange, it's of type Object;  and can't be downcast to Orange (runtime error), because it isn't.

`orange` is an Orange. It can be assigned (without casting) or type Object, and that can then be cast back down to Orange;  because the actual reference (at runtime) *is an instance of* Orange.

Java instance types are set at *creation time*, when the constructor is called. There is no possibility to change the actual type of an object to something else, ever.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the following line will generate a `ClassCastException`

```
Orange o=(Orange)a;
```

> Both o and orange are instatiate in different way. Are they behave the same? (can call all the instance method and field of Orange class)

Answer: No. Because, `orange` is an object of `Orange`, whereas `a` is an `Object`

Answer (score 1):

You will get a `ClassCastException` here `Orange o=(Orange)a`;you can not down cast `Object` to `Orange`.

You can do it

```
Object a=new Orange();
Orange o=(Orange)a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run this code? It'll throw ClassCastException